# Play Framework 2.4 WithApplication call not found in play.api.test

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, integration-testing, specifications

I'm trying to simple test a route in the play framework 2.4 and I follow the guide here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithSpecs2 (testing the router)

here the code

```
package routesAndController

import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._
import org.junit.runner._

import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

/**
  * Created by root on 3/11/16.
  */
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class AnalysisEntryPointTest extends Specification {


  "the AnalysisEntryPoint" should {
    "where the route must be /DomoticRoomServer/Analysis with 200" in new WithApplication {
        val result = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/domoticRoom/analysis")).get

        status(result) must equalTo(OK)
        contentType(result) must beSome.which(_ == "text/html")
    }
  }
}
```

All pretty straight forward. The problem is that the Class 'WithApplication' is not found in the play.api.test package but in the play.test.
I tried to use the object in the api.test but specs2 give me the error:

```
[error] /home/benkio/projects/DomoticRoom/Server/test/routesAndController/AnalysisEntryPointTest.scala:19: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.specs2.execute.AsResult[play.test.WithApplication{val result: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]}]
[error]     "where the route must be /DomoticRoomServer/Analysis with 200" in new WithApplication() {
[error]                                                                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

any suggestions?

---

here the build.sbt:

```
import play.routes.compiler.InjectedRoutesGenerator
import play.sbt.PlayScala

name := """Domotic Room Server"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
  "Millhouse Bintray"  at "http://dl.bintray.com/themillhousegroup/maven"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-cache" % "2.4.6",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.6" % "test",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-junit" % "3.6" % "test",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-scalacheck" % "3.6" % "test",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.9",
  "com.themillhousegroup" %% "play2-reactivemongo-mocks" % "0.11.9_0.4.26"
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
scalacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Yrangepos")

fork in run := true
```

And here my project/plugin.sbt:

```
// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")
```

Comment: Is this the exact code that lead to this error message? The error message leads me to think that there is a statement of type 'Future[Result]' on the last line of the test, while it usually should be a matcher. If the last statement is not a matcher, then you can use one of the predefined methods 'ok', 'todo' or 'fail' on the last line.

Comment: Comment out all other test. Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play has a shortcut to declare the test dependencies, including its own packages. The correct way to add specs2 and Play test classes is:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-cache" % "2.4.6",
    "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.9",
    "com.themillhousegroup" %% "play2-reactivemongo-mocks" % "0.11.9_0.4.26",
    specs2 % Test
)
```

This is [documented here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithSpecs2#Using-specs2). There is also a shortcut to use cache, as also [documented here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaCache#Importing-the-Cache-API). So your dependencies should be declared like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.9",
    "com.themillhousegroup" %% "play2-reactivemongo-mocks" % "0.11.9_0.4.26",
    cache,
    specs2 % Test
)
```

The advantage here is that you don't need to track the dependencies that are compatible with Play. Also, you don't need to repeat Play version all over your dependencies, just at the `project/plugins.sbt` file.

Of course, you can still override and add any other dependencies as you like. You were adding scalacheck, per instance:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.9",
    "com.themillhousegroup" %% "play2-reactivemongo-mocks" % "0.11.9_0.4.26",
    cache,
    specs2 % Test,
    "org.specs2" %% "specs2-scalacheck" % "3.6" % Test
)
```

#### Edit after discussion:

Be welcome to [Dependency Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell). Looks like that `play2-reactivemongo` and `play2-reactivemongo-mocks` are adding a very old specs2 dependency. You can see that by using [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) and running `sbt dependencyTree`. Here is [the complete output](https://gist.github.com/marcospereira/9fd3e0cef5b3e76676c5) and also the relevant section:

```
[info]   +-com.themillhousegroup:play2-reactivemongo-mocks_2.11:0.11.9_0.4.27 [S]
[info]   | +-org.reactivemongo:play2-reactivemongo_2.11:0.11.10 [S]
[info]   | +-org.specs2:specs2_2.11:2.3.13 [S]
```

You can also see that by seeing the code for [play2-reactivemongo-mocks](https://github.com/themillhousegroup/play2-reactivemongo-mocks/blob/master/build.sbt#L21), [play2-reactivemongo](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo/blob/0.11.9/project/Play2-ReactiveMongo.scala#L135) and [Play Framework 2.4.6](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.6/framework/project/Dependencies.scala). These are not compatible versions of specs2 and sbt is not able to evict old versions because the projects are all adding different packages of specs2 (see how play add specific dependencies in contrast with play2-reactivemongo-mocks).

In other words, looks like the test supported offered by play2-reactivemongo-mocks is not compatible with the test support offered by Play. You can open an issue or submit a pull request to solve this, but a new version of play2-reactivemongo-mocks is necessary.

#### A possible solution

Exclude specs2 from play2-reactive dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.10" exclude("org.specs2", "*"),
  "com.themillhousegroup" %% "play2-reactivemongo-mocks" % "0.11.9_0.4.27" exclude("org.specs2", "*"),
  cache,
  specs2 % Test,
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-scalacheck" % "3.6" % Test
)
```

Comment: I read this previously but my dubt is about the scalacheck library, because i want to use it. Anyway I try your solution and get back a feedback right now.

Comment: You can add by hand, or override any dependencies that is added by `specs2 % Test`.

Comment: I made the change but i get this scary error:

[error] error while loading Action, class file '/root/.ivy2/cache/org.specs2/specs2_2.11/jars/specs2_2.11-2.3.13.jar(org/specs2/specification/Action.class)' is broken
[error] (class java.lang.RuntimeException/error reading Scala signature of Action.class: scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$NoSymbol cannot be cast to scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$ClassSymbol)

Comment: For some reason you are getting a very old version of `specs2`. Post your `project/plugins.sbt` file at the question description, please. It could be some trash too, run the following commands: `sbt clean` and then `sbt test`.  Also, see the edits made at my answer.

Comment: Same error :'(
here the code and the stack trace: [](http://pastebin.com/mGyd79na)

Comment: Author of *play2-reactivemongo-mocks* here; thanks to @marcospereira for the excellent detective work and @Benkio for reporting the issue on Github; I've released a new version of the library with the specs2 library dependency brought up-to-date and also changed the configuration to `provided` which should sort this out moving forward. If I find some time I will create a pull request in play2-reactivemongo to do a similar thing.

Comment: @millhouse take a look: https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo/pull/188. I was planning to submit a PR to your project too, but did not had the time. Anyway, Play-ReactiveMongo uses specs2 just at the "test" scope, so it should not affect projects depending on it.

Comment: @millhouse by the way, fell free to edit my answer if you want to. I think that using the newer version is better than excluding the dependencies. Also, thanks for your time to upgrade play2-reactivemongo-socks. ;-)

Comment: @marcospereira great work - you beat me to it! :-) I'll update this answer once your pull request has been merged and there's a version number to specify in the dependency list.